# Magento 2.4.3p1: Get limiter on top on product listing and search page

Tags: magento2, toolbar

How to get the limiter on top on the product listing and search pages on Magento 2.4.3p1?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the template of the block Toolbar **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar**.

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml:29

Moving this line to every where you want in that template.

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml')) ?>
```